# c#: Is there a way to retrieve the cell address in excel from where data begins?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-interop

I'm trying to copy excel data from one sheet to another. Its working fine but the **problem** is: In the source file if the **data doesn't starts** from cell A1 (consider the image below), in this case I want to copy data from the cell **B5**. Here `Some header` is not required. The actual data starts from `Emp ID` cell.

[image: Sample Excel]

***What I've tried*** is, I can provide a `textbox` to input the cell address into it and than start copying the data from the provided cell address. But this introduces manual intervention. I want it automated. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Give us a clear description on *what the rules are for working out where the data starts*. We need them, and for certain a computer program will need them. I.e. by what criteria are the contents of rule 3 *not* considered data? We can't just use a "I know it when I see it" rule.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The data might start anywhere in the sheet. Rule 3 might just be a header like a company or analyst name or something like `Result set` which is actually not related while merging or extracting data.

Comment: Yes, but unless you can come up with some rules we can apply that says what *is* or *isn't* data, how can you expect a computer program to determine this? Like I say, we cannot implement "I know it when I see it". E.g. is it the first cell which also contains non-empty cells immediately below and to its right? *That* is a rule we could implement. But we don't know if that fits *your* definitions.

Comment: Yes I got your point. You're right, it is the first cell which also contains non-empty cells immediately below and to its right. But again that might be in one particular file but not it the other. In the other file, `Emp ID` may start from cell A1 or may be `Some header` might not at all be present (first few records just blank). So in that case my rule will have no effect. I hope you're getting my view...?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess op doesn't want to have any strict rules on the copy operation! As he pointed out that he can provide a `textbox` to do it (but don't want manual intervention), he expects something like automatically fetching the cell where where there is EmpID. Is that how it is?

Comment: The challenge is that either the sheet is generated to serve as input to an application or it isn't. If the sheet is created by someone who understands that it needs to be imported, they will provide some consistency from which you can generate rules. If they don't do that then you're trying to process unpredictable, unstructured input. Stuff will change randomly and make your life miserable. You'll constantly need to add more and more one-off conditions. I've seen it attempted. It's not a happy place to be.

Comment: I completely agree with you @ScottHannen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming some basic criteria, the following code should do it.  The criteria I assume is: 1) if a row contains any merged cells (like your "Some Header") then that isn't the start row.  2) the start cell will contain text in the cell to the right and in the cell below it.

```
private static bool RowIsEmpty(Range range)
{
  foreach (object obj in (object[,])range.Value2)
  {
    if (obj != null && obj.ToString() != "")
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

private static bool CellIsEmpty(Range cell)
{
  if (cell.Value2 != null && cell.Value2.ToString() != "")
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

private Tuple<int, int> ExcelFindStartCell()
{
  var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  excelApp.Visible = true;

  Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx");
  Worksheet worksheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

  // Go through each row.
  for (int row = 1; row < worksheet.Rows.Count; row++)
  {
    Range range = worksheet.Rows[row];

    // Check if the row is empty.
    if (RowIsEmpty(range))
    {
      continue;
    }

    // Check if the row contains any merged cells, if so we'll assume it's
    // some kind of header and move on.
    object mergedCells = range.MergeCells;
    if (mergedCells == DBNull.Value || (bool)mergedCells)
    {
      continue;
    }

    // Find the first column that contains text in this row.
    for (int col = 1; col < range.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
      Range cell = range.Cells[1, col];

      if (CellIsEmpty(cell))
      {
        continue;
      }

      // Now check if the cell to the right also contains text.
      Range rightCell = worksheet.Cells[row, col + 1];

      if (CellIsEmpty(rightCell))
      {
        // No text in right cell, try the next row.
        break;
      }

      // Now check if cell below also contains text.
      Range bottomCell = worksheet.Cells[row + 1, col];

      if (CellIsEmpty(bottomCell))
      {
        // No text in bottom cell, try the next row.
        break;
      }

      // Success!
      workbook.Close();
      excelApp.Quit();
      return new Tuple<int, int>(row, col);
    }
  }

  // Didn't find anything that matched the criteria.
  workbook.Close();
  excelApp.Quit();
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes this works but I've a bit change in the solution. I have updated the answer. Thank you so much gunnerone:)